# Popular grafico com lista - Java Script

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Olá!

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema acadêmico e preciso de um gráfico com as questões erradas por tema de cada aluno. Tenho uma lista com Temas(que seriam o eixo x) e qtdErradas(que seriam o eixo y do gráfico). O meu problema está em popular este gráfico com uma lista. Estou desenvolvendo em Asp.NET e o código do gráfico está em JS. Segue abaixo o js do gráfico.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {

        // Donut Chart
        Morris.Donut({
            element: 'morris-donut-chart',
            data: [
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                {
                    label: item.Tema,
                    value: item.QtdErradas
                },
            }
            ],
            resize: true
        });    
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Aparece algum erro de JavaScript na console do Browser? Não vejo nenhum erro na sua View.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, tive umas dificuldades em ralação a popular um gráfico com dados também. Não utilizei ajax e sim Jquery recebendo um retorno json. Utilizo também o HighCharts.

a funcao foi

```
var variavel_array = [];

$.getJSON('PASSO A ROTA', function(resposta){
  $.each(resposta, function(index){
    //Aqui vc deve criar um array para receber os valores dos campos retornados
    variavel_array[index] = resposta[index].pega_campo_json;
});
    //agr e so colocar a variavel_array no seu grafico.
});
```

Na minha rota:

```
var dados = consulta do banco e pega a resposta e armazena na variavel
return Json(dados , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

Pronto, assim a function que recebe como parametro (resposta) ira receber os dados que virao da rota. Recebendo esses dados ira armazenar na variavel como array e assim e so jogar no grafico

Answer (score 0):

Olá,
Cara, primeira dica: Não misture seus valores do seu Model com seu código JavaScript.

O que pode ser feito neste caso é criar uma nova Action que retorne um Json com informação necessária para popular este gráfico:

```
public JsonResult GetMorrisData(){
//Aqui vai retornar a informação do seu array;
}
```

e então no JavaScript você solicita a informação via XHR e popula o gráfico:

```
    window.onload = function () {
    //Usarei JQuery para facilitar:
    $.getJSON("/controller/getmorrisdata")
    .success(function(data){
     // Donut Chart
            Morris.Donut({
              element: 'morris-donut-chart',
              data: data, //Isto por as informações já serão retornadas no padrão de objeto corretamente
              resize: true
            });
        });
     };
```

Comment: apesar se ser uma dica valida para o aprendizado do AP, não acredito que isto vá resolver o problema do mesmo, afinal você apenas populando o gráfico de forma assíncrona.